# Storing the image into the external DataBase

Tags: android, image-processing

Hai!
   I am new to android. I want to store the images into the external database such as oracle or Mysql. How can i achieve this.
Any answers will be appreciated..
Thanks in advance...

Regards,
Balaji.k

Comment: Why have you not accepted any answers to *any* your questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to upload them to your server using something like Apache's HTTP Client (via a POST or PUT) and them store them using a [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) data type.